# How to fix the bug with svg background?

Tags: html, css, svg, background

I have one issue.

[image]

My `svg backgound` isn't full. Part of the background was gone.

It's must look like this
[image]

```css
section {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url('https://svgshare.com/i/6RG.svg');
  height: 32px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div></div>
</section>
```

I tried use `background-size: 100% 100%;`, some variation of `background-position`. But it didn't help me.

Code of svg file.

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 1000 32" enable-background="new 0 0 1000 32" xml:space="preserve">
<line fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="0" y1="0" x2="484.8" y2="0"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="484.8" y1="0" x2="500" y2="32"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="500" y1="32" x2="1000" y2="32"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: `It's must look like this` --> it looks like this for me

Comment: @TemaniAfif, Sorry if I made the mistake. I'm not from GB or USA.

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi check your browser zoom level?

Comment: @evolutionxbox, default, 100%

Comment: Unable to replicate. If your demo does not show it (and, in Chrome it does not)...we have a problem

Comment: Can you give context to where you are seeing this issue? E.g. browser/os?

Comment: there is no mistake, i meant it's working for me :)

Comment: @TemaniAfif, Open it in the full screen

Comment: @evolutionxbox, I use firefox, win10

Answer (score 0):

Some really creative solution, but it works. I used before and after to fill up the empty space with borders. When the image gets too small.

```css
section {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url('https://svgshare.com/i/6RG.svg');
  height: 32px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
div:before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 1px solid #8e8e8e;
  width: 40%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
div:after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #8e8e8e;
  width: 40%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
@media (max-width:937px) {
  div:after{
    display: none;
  }
  div:before{
    display:none;
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Uploaded an edit. There is a better fix, probably, but it does it's job :)

Comment: Yeah, the problem is the height. What is should do is create my own SVG. Only the diagonal part in the middle. So you can add borders, with width: calc(50% - $half-svg-width);